# Performing an unknown amount of animations sequentially

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, grand-central-dispatch, skaction

I am creating a game where the user can move a `SKShapeNode` around. Now, I am trying to write a utility function that will perform back-to-back animations sequentially.

### Description of what I'm Trying

I first dispatch_async to a serial thread. This thread then calls a dispatch_sync on the main thread to perform an animation. Now, to make the animations run sequentially, I would like to block the `GlobalSerialAnimationQueue` until the animation is completed on the main thread. By doing this, I (theoretically) would be able to run animations sequentially. My code is pasted below for more description

```
func moveToCurrentPosition() {
    let action = SKAction.moveTo(self.getPositionForCurrRowCol(), duration: 1.0)
    dispatch_async(GlobalSerialAnimateQueue) {
        //this just creates an action to move to a point
        dispatch_sync(GlobalMainQueue, { 
            self.userNode!.runAction(action) {
                //inside the completion block now want to continue
                //WOULD WANT TO TRIGGER THREAD TO CONTINUE HERE
            }
        })
        //WOULD LIKE TO PAUSE HERE, THIS BLOCK FINISHING ONLY WHEN THE ANIMATION IS COMPLETE
    }
}
```

So, my question is, how would I write a function that can take in requests for animations, and then perform them sequentially? What grand-central-dispatch tools should I use, or should I be trying a completely different approach?

Comment: Any reason for not using `SKAction.sequence`?

Comment: @ZeMoon I don't know very much about `SKAction.sequence`, but I have chosen to do it this way because this animation takes a while and can be called an unknown amount of times by the user.

Comment: Okay... Use whatever works for you, however if you look at the answer I posted you will see it's simplicity, and can probably start using the same for your game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using a grand-central-dispatch semaphore. My updated code is here.

```
func moveToCurrentPosition() {

    let action = SKAction.moveTo(self.getPositionForCurrRowCol(), duration: Animation.USER_MOVE_DURATION)
    dispatch_async(GlobalSerialAnimateQueue) {
        let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        dispatch_sync(GlobalMainQueue, {
            self.userNode!.runAction(action) {
                //signal done
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
            }
        })
        //wait here...
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for this. Also dispatch_xxx methods doesn't respect view's, scene's or node's paused state. The right choice is what ZeMoon pointed.

Comment: Ouch, is there really no other way? Facing a similar situation where depositing the actions into a sequence is not an option (they *may* be executed in sequence, or they may be single stepped through under user control, or run backwards, or any other non-predetermined order)

Answer (score 1):

SpriteKit provides a much simpler and intuitive API for running actions in sequence. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/sequence:).

You can simply perform actions as a sequence of events, with blocks in between or as completion:

```
let action = SKAction.moveTo(self.getPositionForCurrRowCol(), duration: Animation.USER_MOVE_DURATION)

let otherAction = SKAction.runBlock({ 
            //Perform completion here.
        })

self.userNode!.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, otherAction]))
```